# Come up with a reasonable estimate for number of people who have at least $X

Tags: estimation

Suppose that we know according to a survey, that the number of people who have at least USD 1million in the US is 3 million people. How can we come up with a reasonable estimate for the number of people who have at least USD 2million without doing a separate survey?

Comment: If this post is intended as a specific example of a general question about how to extrapolate survey results, then for the most general answer -- one that is just as valid as any other -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouija.

Answer (score 1):

Th US Census Bureau conducts a regular census and intervening surveys that collect information on a number of economic variables for households and individuals.  If you go to their [page on wealth and asset ownership](https://www.census.gov/topics/income-poverty/wealth.html) you will see that they have released data tables up to 2017.  Unfortunately, it appears that their data on wealth is for households, rather than for individuals.  You might be able to find data on individuals if you have a look at the data on their site or call them to make inquiries.

In statistical terms, the simplest thing to do here is to try to find data on the distribution of wealth (e.g., published percentiles of wealth) and then use some reasonable interpolation method to interpolate between the published values to get an estimate for the wealth value of interest to you.  This will require you to find wealth percentile data for individuals with the percentiles going up high enough to equal or exceed the value that is of interest to you.